# Determining future age in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project that requires me to implement a method that determines a persons age on the day after labor day; which falls on the first Monday of September every year.

This method will be used in future years, so it will need to determine the current year and the age of a person on the day after labor day.

Below is the code I used to get the students current age:

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
       age--;
    }
    return age;  //this returns the students current age
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: Just replace today with the the day after labor day ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed the code around a good bit. So it can handle more situations.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y6kTc/

```
function getAge(birthday, whatDay) {
    var whatDay = whatDay || new Date(),
        birthday = typeof birthday.getTime === "function" ? birthday : new Date(birthday)

    var age = whatDay.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear(),
        m = whatDay.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && whatDay.getDate() < birthday.getDate())) {
       age--
    }

    return age  //this returns the students current age    
}
```

By default you can pass in a date string or a date object for the birthday and get the current birthday `getAge( new Date("5/29/1988") )` or `getAge("5/29/1988")`

The real magic happens with the whatDay parameter. With it you can set a day in the future to be calculated `getAge("5/29/1988", new Date("9/1/2014"))`

To get a day like labor day you could pass in a self invoking function to calculate that day like so:

```
getAge( "5/29/1988", (function(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear(),
        day = 1

    date.setMonth(8)
    date.setDate(day) //8 for September, 1 for the first

    while (date.getDay() !== 1) {
        date.setDate(day++)
    }

    return date        
})(new Date()) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace today with the day after labor day:

```
function firstMonday (month, year)
{
    // allow month to be actual month and not zero based
    var d = new Date(year, month - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    var day = 0

    // check if first of the month is a Sunday, if so set date to the second

    if (d.getDay() == 0) 
    {
        day = 2
        d = d.setDate(day)
        d = new Date(d)
    }

    // check if first of the month is a Monday, if so return the date, otherwise get to the Monday following the first of the month

    else if (d.getDay() != 1) 
    {
        day = 9-(d.getDay())
        d = d.setDate(day)
        d = new Date(d)
    }

    return d;
}

function getFutureAge(dateString) 
{
    var today = new Date();
    var monday = firstMonday(9, today.getFullYear());
    var laborDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 9, monday.getDay() + 1, 0, 0, 0);
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = laborDay.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = laborDay.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
       age--;

    return age;  //this returns the students current age
}

console.log(getFutureAge('09/01/1996'));
```

Output:

```
18
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4syBQ/